# Pick alert sound - swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, picker

I'm new in swift and want to pick an alert sound for a timer or something.
How can I open this list, to choose one of these sounds?[Alert sound list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtiVG.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to use the system sounds in your app.

However, you could include your own sound files and present them in a UITableView. The user can then select from one of these sounds.